# Cannot Programatically Select MudTreeView

Tags: razor, mudblazor

This example is a slight variation of the [MudBlazor examples](https://mudblazor.com/components/treeview): It contains of a tree, where I programmatically try to select the "content" node:

```html
<MudPaper Width="300px" Elevation="0">
    <MudTreeView @bind-SelectedValue="SelectedValue" Hover="true">
        <MudTreeViewItem @bind-Expanded="@folderOneExpanded" Value="@(".vscode")" Icon="@(folderOneExpanded ? Icons.Custom.Uncategorized.FolderOpen : Icons.Custom.Uncategorized.Folder)">
            <MudTreeViewItem Value="@("launch.json")" Icon="@Icons.Custom.FileFormats.FileCode" />
            <MudTreeViewItem Value="@("tasks.json")" Icon="@Icons.Custom.FileFormats.FileCode" />
        </MudTreeViewItem>
        <MudTreeViewItem @bind-Expanded="@folderTwoExpanded" Value="@("content")" Icon="@(folderTwoExpanded ? Icons.Custom.Uncategorized.FolderOpen : Icons.Custom.Uncategorized.Folder)">
            <MudTreeViewItem Value="@("logo.png")" Icon="@Icons.Custom.FileFormats.FileImage" />
        </MudTreeViewItem>
    </MudTreeView>
</MudPaper>

<MudText Style="width: 100%" Typo="@Typo.subtitle1">Selected item: @SelectedValue</MudText>
```

```cs
    string SelectedValue { get; set; }
    bool folderOneExpanded;
    bool folderTwoExpanded;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        SelectedValue = "content";
    }
```

*(Try [interactive example](https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/mEGwEolHweLsiOcB))*

However when I run the program, the content node is not selected, even though everything else looks like it should be.

Why is that? How do I programmatically select nodes in a `MudTreeView`?

Other variants that do not work:

```html
<MudTreeView SelectedValue="content" T="string">
```

```html
<MudTreeViewItem Value="@("launch.json")" Icon="@Icons.Custom.FileFormats.FileCode" Selected="true"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign `Activated` to true on `MudTreeViewItem` you want to get selected. Then on the first render, call the `StateHasChanged` method if you want to do it after the component has been initialized. This should do the trick.

## Example

Here's a modified version of your code:

```
<MudPaper Width="300px" Elevation="0">
    <MudTreeView @bind-SelectedValue="SelectedValue" Hover="true">
        <MudTreeViewItem @bind-Expanded="@folderOneExpanded" Value="@(".vscode")" Icon="@(folderOneExpanded ? Icons.Custom.Uncategorized.FolderOpen : Icons.Custom.Uncategorized.Folder)">
            <MudTreeViewItem Value="@("launch.json")" Icon="@Icons.Custom.FileFormats.FileCode" />
            <MudTreeViewItem Value="@("tasks.json")" Icon="@Icons.Custom.FileFormats.FileCode" />
        </MudTreeViewItem>
        <MudTreeViewItem Activated=@ContentSelected @bind-Expanded="@folderTwoExpanded" Value="@("content")" Icon="@(folderTwoExpanded ? Icons.Custom.Uncategorized.FolderOpen : Icons.Custom.Uncategorized.Folder)">
            <MudTreeViewItem Value="@("logo.png")" Icon="@Icons.Custom.FileFormats.FileImage" />
        </MudTreeViewItem>
    </MudTreeView>
</MudPaper>

<MudText Style="width: 100%" Typo="@Typo.subtitle1">Selected item: @SelectedValue</MudText>

@code {
    string SelectedValue { get; set; }
    bool ContentSelected { get; set; }
    bool folderOneExpanded;
    bool folderTwoExpanded;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        ContentSelected = true;
    }

    protected override void OnAfterRender(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender)
            StateHasChanged();
    }
}
```

https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/GuQmOyvzQshYmJie

Comment: What is the difference between Activated and Selected?

Comment: Activated is also causing a bad side effect on https://mudblazor.com/components/treeview#server-side-data

it causes somehow a deadlock takes much longer. I have looked the source code  [Parameter]
        [Category(CategoryTypes.TreeView.Selecting)]
        public bool Activated
        {
            get => _isSelected;
            set
            {
                _ = MudTreeRoot?.UpdateSelected(this, value);
            }
        }
it update Selected seems and doing more. What is the sense, strange implementation.